# PhotoSwipe next/back icon

Tags: html, css, photoswipe

Is anyone even use PhotoSwipe before ?

https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe

I stuck at image left and right (back and next)

like this image.

[image]

I don't want the other icon. I want to know how to fix this.

I already try to disable image inside css but it's still not work

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following options available to `show/hide` photoswipe `buttons/elements`.

for more info read docs [here](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/options.html)

```
var options = {    
    history: false,
    focus: false,
    closeEl: true,
    captionEl: true,
    fullscreenEl: true,
    zoomEl: true,
    shareEl: true,
    counterEl: true,
    arrowEl: true,
    preloaderEl: true
  };
```

Comment: But the problem is on button right and next. It's show other icon around the arrow icon. Maybe It's a problem with css link image I don't know how it's work. @JyotiPathania

Comment: @B.Godoak The problem is related to `background-position`, `width` and `height` check your css you have missed that property or some other property might have overriding the  library css property.

Comment: Wow! It's working now. I change `width` and `height`. Thank you @JyotiPathania and how can I flag this comment as the answer ?

Comment: @B.Godoak I have the same problem with icons, some pointers on how exactly you fixed the problem? Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, Fixed it by just adjusting the width and height a bit of the buttons. But had to link the CSS a bit differently because it was getting overriden.

Comment: @hellmit100 It's a long time haha, but I think i do it with fix width and height